# Remove items from a tuple in string format

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, tuples, string-formatting

Here is my string

```
a = '(20.0, 8.0, 8.0, 37.0)'
```

and i want only first three items in this format

```
str = 20.0x8.0x8.0
```

and store the last item in a list.

```
leftover = [37.0]
```

Earlier I had only three dimensions in the string so I was using replace function multiple times to convert it.

```
converted = str(''.join(str(v) for v in a)).replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(", ","x")
```

I know it's not the most pythonic way but it was doing the trick. But I have no clue how to remove an element from str(tuple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

a = '(20.0, 8.0, 8.0, 37.0)'

a_tupl = ast.literal_eval(a)

string = 'x'.join(map(str, a_tupl[:3]))  # 20.0x8.0x8.0
leftover = [a_tupl[-1]]  # [37.0]
```

---

Don't name your variable as `str`, because it shadows the built-in.

Comment: Yaya! I was not gonna name it "str", it was just to ask the question.. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
from ast import literal_eval
str1 = "x".join([str(k) for k in literal_eval(a)[:3]])
leftover = [literal_eval(a)[-1]]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
'20.0x8.0x8.0'
[37.0]
```

Without importing `ast` :

```
str1 = "x".join([k for k in a.replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",")[:3]])
leftover = [float(a.replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",")[-1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple LC over your splitted string to get back a list of values from the string representation of a tuple.
No libraries, just a simple python oneliner...:

```
a = '(20.0, 8.0, 8.0, 37.0)'

l = [float(v) for v in a[1:-1].split(',')]
# [20.0, 8.0, 8.0, 37.0]
```

Then it's as easy to create the two results you need:

```
str('x'.join([str(v) for v in l[:3]]))
# '20.0x8.0x8.0'

[l[-1]]
# [37.0]
```